# Automate Rule Creation

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, rules

Can a script/macro/rule that parses a subject line also create a new rule that moves any subsequent emails with the parsed string ,via "subject contains", to an existing folder? I'm essentially trying to automate rule creation in outlook.

I can't find a good references or lists of actions available to even know if it's possible. Any guide in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: For background, I get an email every time a case new case is assigned and the 20-24 characters in the email subject are the case number. Currently, I manually create a new rule to forward all emails with the case number in the subject line to a My Cases folder. I need to do this because my inbox is auto-forwarded 200 other emails a day and is a nightmare to go through one by one.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN article [Managing Rules in the Outlook Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860622.aspx) provides all required information for working with rules programmatically.